# What is the equivalent of selenium javascript executor code in c#?

Tags: java, c#, selenium

Java code

```
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("window.open();");
```

C#?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a Question and Answer site, not a code translation service. Try to translate the code yourself first, then come to us when you are stuck, making sure to show us what you have tried.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6229769/execute-javascript-using-selenium-webdriver-in-c-sharp

Answer (score -1):

```
IJavaScriptExecutor js = driver as IJavaScriptExecutor; 
string title = (string)js.ExecuteScript("window.open();");
```