# Using jQuery in C# code

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, selenium, webdriver

I'm using Visual Studio 2015 with Selenium adds for creating web tests, and i need to implement some jQuery code in my C# code. Is there a way for that? if it's help i download jQuery in NuGet package manager, but still i don't know how to implement jQuery code in c#.

I need it to scroll bar created in http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller/ and i go to use

```
$('#ID').mCustomScrollbar("scrollTo", 200)
```

I'm begginer so if i need to implement some

```
using
```

or other things pls mention :D
Thx for all help
Janer

Comment: jquery is a javascript library. You would typically use it in a web page. It has nothing to do with csharp.

Comment: why do you want to write it on server side code?

Comment: an easy way for having experience with jQuery is web console. You can try it on you project if jQuery is implemented.

Comment: i'm using C# for writing my tests, and that scrollbar is created in jQuery, so  if jQuery belongs to javascript, how i can implement javascript in my code? Is there any possibility??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look into [`ExecuteScript()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6229769/execute-javascript-using-selenium-webdriver-in-c-sharp) to execute custom javascript in a browser with selenium:

```
IWebElement element = driver.FindElement(By.Id("myid"));
IJavaScriptExecutor js = driver as IJavaScriptExecutor;
js.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].mCustomScrollbar('scrollTo', 200);", element);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't. jQuery is a Javascript library for webdevelopment. You can only use jQuery in Javascript files (or script blocks in your HTML).

Comment: and using java in c# either is not possible in simple way. I figured it out few  min ago. so i just need to write my tests in java directly.
Thx for trying help me :)

Comment: You can't use javascript* (if you mean that) in C# no, only in ASP.NET (which is used to create websites). If you mean java, I don't know how it's related to this question.

Comment: Try not to simply say 'It cannot be done'. The entire point is there are cases where you may need to use javascript inside C#. It's possible, see this this example: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/7d3362/use-javascript-function-in-window-application-C-Sharp1/

Not the cleanest example, but it displays using javascript in C# (though admittedly not in the same context as within this question).

Answer (score 0):

My finally code to use jQuery based on alecxe code is

```
string cssElement = driver.FindElement(By.||all the way u want||).GetAttribute("id");
IJavaScriptExecutor js = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;
js.ExecuteScript("$(\"#\"+\"" + cssElement + "\".replace(/:/g,\"\\\\:\")).mCustomScrollbar('scrollTo',[200,0]);");
```

it's working (for me). If some problem try first change barlocation and element location. it's for vertical bar ;)

I hope that help someone in future