# Selenium run javascript in firefox console

Tags: javascript, c#, selenium

I'm looking to see does a particular object exist on my page. By opening firebug and entering the following javascript into the console I can visually see the object myself.

```
$("#grid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.data()[0]
```

How can I achieve this with Selenium IDE or selenium webdriver (C#). I have tried runScript in the IDE but it doesn't seem to do anything. As in it turns green no matter what "Target" is entered when I run the test.

Comment: Did you try this answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6285793/2932244)?

Comment: I didn't see that link. Very useful, thank you!