# Selenium python - element is not clickable at point

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, web-scraping, instagram

I'm trying to get follow button text in instagram post page (page example - https://www.instagram.com/p/BD2C8pQwO8X/)

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.set_window_size(1024, 768)
driver.get('https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/')
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
username_field = driver.find_element_by_name('username')
password_field = driver.find_element_by_name('password')
username_field.send_keys(user_login)
password_field.send_keys(user_pass)
password_field.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
time.sleep(5)


def find_tag():
    search_field = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//nav/div/div/div/div/input')
    search_field.send_keys('#moscow')
    time.sleep(1)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="react-root"]/section/nav/div/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div/a[1]').click()


def follow_from_tag():
    top_20_posts = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//article/div/div/div/a')
    for post in top_20_posts:
        post.click()
        time.sleep(1.5)
        print(driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/article/header/span/button').text)



find_tag()
time.sleep(2)
follow_from_tag()
```

but got an error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Element is not clickable at point (511, 415). Other element would receive the click: <a class="_c2kdw" href="javascript:;" role="button" data-reactid=".1.1.0.0.1.$https=2//scontent-arn2-1=1cdninstagram=1com/t51=12885-15/e15/12479233_260398184295103_1013244176_n=1jpg?ig_cache_key=0MTIyMjM0Nzg4MzM1MDYzNTQzOA%3D%3D=12.0.0.1"></a>
  (Session info: chrome=49.0.2623.110)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.9.248307,platform=Mac OS X 10.10.5 x86_64
```

what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: seems like another element is overlapping the element you want to click. at which line you get the error?

Comment: File "/Users/kr/PycharmProjects/education_py/instagram.py", line 24, in follow_from_tag
    post.click()

Comment: take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19763087/1033737

Comment: I ran your code  and `//article/div/div/div/a` seems incorrect, what are you trying to get?

Comment: if i try to click on it - driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/article/header/span/button').click() - it works, but don't return the text of this button

Comment: @KonstantinRusanov, what do you want from the final page?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham i want to get this button - https://yadi.sk/i/Jk2e3-JIqnKsg - text, to use it in IF ELSE to check account which i already followed.

Answer (score 1):

This gets what you want:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

def wait(dr, x):
    element = WebDriverWait(dr, 5).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, x))
    )
    return element

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.set_window_size(1024, 768)
driver.get('https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/')
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
username_field = driver.find_element_by_name('username')
password_field = driver.find_element_by_name('password')
username_field.send_keys("user")
password_field.send_keys("pass")
password_field.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)    

def find_tag():
    search_field = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//nav/div/div/div/div/input')
    search_field.send_keys('moscow')
    wait(driver, '//*[@id="react-root"]/section/nav/div/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div/a[1]').click()

def follow_from_tag():
    top_20_posts = [a.get_attribute("href") for a in
                    driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[contains(@href,'?tagged=moscow')]")[:20]]
    for href in top_20_posts:
        driver.get(href)
        print(href)
        btn = wait(driver, "//button[text()='Follow']")
       # btn.click() # uncomment to follow
```

The output of the prints:

```
https://www.instagram.com/p/BD249tsxEbl/?tagged=moscow
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement object at 0x7fa717d79810>
https://www.instagram.com/p/BD2puxzELOu/?tagged=moscow
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement object at 0x7fa717d79790>
https://www.instagram.com/p/BD2jrmyP8ec/?tagged=moscow
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement object at 0x7fa717d79750>
https://www.instagram.com/p/BD2v9NyvzIs/?tagged=moscow
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement object at 0x7fa717d79810>
https://www.instagram.com/p/BD2qkcZm8cg/?tagged=moscow
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement object at 0x7fa717d79790>
https://www.instagram.com/p/BD2sEWzLlEF/?tagged=moscow
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement object at 0x7fa717d79750>
https://www.instagram.com/p/BD25VA2vI6t/?tagged=moscow
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement object at 0x7fa717d79810>
https://www.instagram.com/p/BD2fRXoB1t2/?tagged=moscow
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement object at 0x7fa717d79790>
https://www.instagram.com/p/BD2jYlfE0Yw/?tagged=moscow
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement object at 0x7fa717d79750>
https://www.instagram.com/p/BD2s0PtoRP1/?tagged=moscow
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement object at 0x7fa717d79810>
https://www.instagram.com/p/BD2mn_QBQPK/?tagged=moscow
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement object at 0x7fa717d79790>
https://www.instagram.com/p/BD2zTmqM-5h/?tagged=moscow
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement object at 0x7fa717d79750>
https://www.instagram.com/p/BD2q6Qfqc5q/?tagged=moscow
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement object at 0x7fa717d79810>
https://www.instagram.com/p/BD2iivvDbiO/?tagged=moscow
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement object at 0x7fa717d79790>
https://www.instagram.com/p/BD2-WU2msdO/?tagged=moscow
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement object at 0x7fa717d79750>
https://www.instagram.com/p/BD2Qa2Rn0GV/?tagged=moscow
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement object at 0x7fa717d79810>
https://www.instagram.com/p/BD2ffCZDR8L/?tagged=moscow
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement object at 0x7fa717d79790>
https://www.instagram.com/p/BD2kqDhwywb/?tagged=moscow
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement object at 0x7fa717d79750>
https://www.instagram.com/p/BD2r4M7lf-h/?tagged=moscow
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement object at 0x7fa717d79810>
https://www.instagram.com/p/BD2t3PTAlJC/?tagged=moscow
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement object at 0x7fa717d79790>
```

You might want to add error handling and use better xpaths but it gets what you need, just uncomment the `btn.click()` if you want to follow.

I missed you want to check the text, if you want to check the text, we can use contains with `"Follow"` as the word to match:

```
def follow_from_tag():
    top_20_posts = [a.get_attribute("href") for a in
                    driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[contains(@href,'?tagged=moscow')]")[:20]]
    for href in top_20_posts:
        driver.get(href)
        print(href)
        btn = wait(driver, "//button[contains(text(),'Follow')]")
        print(btn.text)
```

The output now after I randomly chose one to follow:

```
https://www.instagram.com/p/BD23RGrkLEN/?tagged=moscow
FOLLOW
https://www.instagram.com/p/BD2jrmyP8ec/?tagged=moscow
FOLLOW
https://www.instagram.com/p/BD249tsxEbl/?tagged=moscow
FOLLOWING
https://www.instagram.com/p/BD2v9NyvzIs/?tagged=moscow
FOLLOW
https://www.instagram.com/p/BD2qkcZm8cg/?tagged=moscow
FOLLOW
https://www.instagram.com/p/BD2sEWzLlEF/?tagged=moscow
FOLLOW
https://www.instagram.com/p/BD25VA2vI6t/?tagged=moscow
FOLLOW
https://www.instagram.com/p/BD2fRXoB1t2/?tagged=moscow
FOLLOW
https://www.instagram.com/p/BD2s0PtoRP1/?tagged=moscow
FOLLOW
https://www.instagram.com/p/BD2jYlfE0Yw/?tagged=moscow
FOLLOW
https://www.instagram.com/p/BD2mn_QBQPK/?tagged=moscow
FOLLOW
https://www.instagram.com/p/BD2zTmqM-5h/?tagged=moscow
FOLLOW
https://www.instagram.com/p/BD2-WU2msdO/?tagged=moscow
FOLLOW
https://www.instagram.com/p/BD2q6Qfqc5q/?tagged=moscow
FOLLOW
https://www.instagram.com/p/BD2iivvDbiO/?tagged=moscow
FOLLOW
https://www.instagram.com/p/BD29pcrDs6o/?tagged=moscow
FOLLOW
https://www.instagram.com/p/BD2Qa2Rn0GV/?tagged=moscow
FOLLOW
https://www.instagram.com/p/BD2ffCZDR8L/?tagged=moscow
FOLLOW
https://www.instagram.com/p/BD2kqDhwywb/?tagged=moscow
FOLLOW
https://www.instagram.com/p/BD2r4M7lf-h/?tagged=moscow
FOLLOW
```

So you just need an `if btn.text.lower() == "follow"` etc..

Answer (score 0):

The URL you posted doesn't contain a `//*[@id="react-root"]/section/nav/div/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div/a[1]`. But I assume that when moving the (virtual) mouse cursor from your `search_field` to the element you want to click, it causes some MouseOver effect on the page, in the sense that an overlay pops up or something, hiding the clickable element behind itself.

I had the same problem and solved it like this:
[How to avoid MouseOver on Selenium Click()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35293881/how-to-avoid-mouseover-on-selenium-click)

Comment: That part does work. It brings you to `https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/moscow/`, it is on a completely different page to the url posted

Comment: Yes, that part leads me to top popular posts with tag moscow, but after i'm open each post and want to print follow button text