# How can I replace the method Click on Selenium C#?

Tags: c#, selenium

In my web page

```
<button class="btn btn-small dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                       Name Button
<span class="caret"/>
</button>
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
<input id="---" type="hidden" value="---"/>
<li>
<label class="Styledcheckbox">
<div class="Styledcheckbox">
Tranche A                                         
</label>
</li>
 .....
```

Manuallly when I click on the button "**Name Button**" a popup menu appears but When I use the method Click() of selenium the popup menu apperas then it will be closed and in this case i can't detect the text on the popup .

```
IWebElement element = null;
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
element = wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(locator));
element.Click();
```

How can i replace this code, and the popup menu stay opened until i select a value from the popup.

I have tried also:

```
 Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
 IWebElement element = null;
 WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
 element = wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(locator));
 builder.MoveToElement(element).Release();
```

Comment: Is this issue occurred in all browser or any specific browser???

Comment: chrome, i did'nt try with other browser!

Comment: Please open your console on browser and try to click on button using JavaScript...If popupMenu appears and hold.. then us JS to automate here..

Comment: How can use JS to automate with selenium and C#??!!

Comment: You should follow this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6229769/execute-javascript-using-selenium-webdriver-in-c-sharp

Comment: I have tried :                                                                                                                ` IWebElement element = null;
                WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
               element = wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(locator));
                IJavaScriptExecutor executor = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;
                executor.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].click();", element);` But i faced the same problem.

Comment: yes! the popup menu appears then closes.!

Comment: Can you try once all your stuff to other browser???

Comment: Can you share your website url???

Comment: the website is not accessible from the outside. It's confidential application. The problem that i faced some problem with the other browsers!

Comment: Can you tell me manually your popup menu opens after clicking or on mouse over on button???

Comment: Execute this script once..

function triggerMouseEvent (node, eventType) {
       var clickEvent = document.createEvent ('MouseEvents');
       clickEvent.initEvent (eventType, true, true);
       node.dispatchEvent (clickEvent);
       }
    triggerMouseEvent (arguments[0], "mouseover");
    triggerMouseEvent (arguments[0], "mousedown");
    triggerMouseEvent (arguments[0], "mouseup");
    triggerMouseEvent (arguments[0], "click");

Comment: manually, the popup oppens when i click.And i'm trying your proposition i will tell u about the result.

Comment: The same problem!!! it's weird! It's my first time that i faced such a problem.

Comment: Check if the js executes something different when you click manually or in selenium. Try to debbug it

Comment: manually when i click a popup menu is oppened, and with selenium the popup menu oppens then closes!

Comment: When i try with mouse events(JS) Nothing happens.