# Can title of browser be changed in selenium c#?

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

In Selenium using Webdriver and C# how we can change the browser title?
Using javascript and jQuery as follow:

```
document.title='XXX'
```

or

```
$('title')[0].text='XXX'
```

Have no effect although we can change the title using Web developers tool console.

Is there any restriction in changing browser title in Selenium?

**UPDATE:**

Problem roots: Using JavaScriptExecutor that has been initialized with the driver on a window which had been closed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As said in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6285793/1543596) answer,
you can run javascript code from selenium.

Your code will be like this:

```
WebDriver driver; // assume assigned elsewhere
IJavaScriptExecutor js = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;
string title = (string)js.ExecuteScript("document.title = 'hello'");
```

And it will change browser title.

**Edit**

Here full working code:

```
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.AddArguments("--start-maximized");
        var driver = new ChromeDriver(options);

        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.google.com");
        IJavaScriptExecutor js = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;
        string title = (string)js.ExecuteScript("document.title = 'hello'");
```

And here result:
[image]

Comment: It seems my problem was in JavaScriptExecutor that I used. I had been initialized it somewhere else.

Comment: Bit of a necropost, but you can also treat driver as an IJavaScriptExecutor directly, ie
((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript()