# How to verify if the name of image contains 5.0 in its name using c# selenium

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, testing, automation

I want to verify if the image name contains certain text or not. Whats the best way to do it

I have attached an image for reference as below:

[image]

Comment: Do you mean the src or the alt?

Comment: Image name in src

Comment: You can use JQuery to check the if the value of either of these attributes contains "5.0" like follows:

$("img[src*='5.0']")

This will get you all img elements from the dom whose src value contains the string "5.0".

Comment: If you want to check if that specific element has a src which contains "5.0" you'll need to get that element on it's own first, to do so you'll need to give your element an id or use a combination of JQuery selectors to select it via unique key (for instance you might select it via it's alt text). I would suggest adding an id to the element.

Comment: Please read why [a screenshot of code is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Paste the code and properly format it instead.

Answer (score -1):

One way you could do this (using js) is with the `.indexOf` method. In your case, you could use code like this:

```
// If you gave your img element an id="picture",
// you could get your src text with this line:
var imageSource = document.getElementById("picture").src;

// boolean for whether or not 5.0 exists in the source
var exists = false;

// indexOf will return the index that 5.0 is located at
// if it does not exist, it will return -1
// here, I evaluate if the index of 5.0 is not -1
// if it is not -1, that means it does exist 
if (imageSource.indexOf("5.0") != -1)
     exists = true;
```

Here is the w3schools link for the `.indexOf` method:
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof.asp

Yes, this is JavaScript. Which you CAN use: [Execute JavaScript using Selenium WebDriver in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6229769/execute-javascript-using-selenium-webdriver-in-c-sharp)

Hope this helps, good luck!

Comment: @JeffC https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6229769/execute-javascript-using-selenium-webdriver-in-c-sharp

Comment: I know how to run JS in C#. Your answer here doesn't cover that. See [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/290046/if-the-question-is-specifically-about-a-certain-language-is-an-answer-in-anothe).

Comment: @JeffC You should look at the answer from Dennis Jaheruddin from the link you just sent me.

Comment: @JeffC I will be honest and say I have not worked with Selenium WebDriver. However I do know C# very well but didn't want to assume normal C# code would work. Because no one had answered, I figured I would do my best to solve the problem. Can't blame a guy for trying. Instead of trying to run me down you could always answer the question?

Comment: I used to do the same thing (give answers in a language other than that requested) when I was learning the site, then others educated me on the site rules. While I may not always agree with them, I try to follow them. My intention was not to "run you down", it was to inform you of the site rules.

Comment: I know the answer but the reason I haven't answered is that the OP needs to learn the site rules. They need to [ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) that meets the acceptable criteria for SO. I feel like if I answer a poor question, then I've taught someone else that it's OK to ask poor questions. Making them go through the process of learning how to ask a good question and fixing their question to fit those criteria makes SO better. THEN... I will answer the question. It's a longer process in the short term but in the long term it makes the site better.