# Execute JavaScript querySelectorAll on especial element using Selenium

Tags: javascript, c#, selenium

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6229769/execute-javascript-using-selenium-webdriver-in-c-sharp) I want find an element in my JavaScript code by some thing like this:

```
     IJavaScriptExecutor js = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;
     string count = 
         js.ExecuteScript(
         "return document.querySelectorAll('ul.tag-list > li.tag-item').length")
         .ToString();
```

And It works correctly. But I need run my JavaScript code in the special piece of the page not the whole of a document.
Is it anyway?

Comment: You need to write more accurate CSS selector for that. Share your HTML.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can use `querySelectorAll` on an *element* as well. So select the element (via `querySelector` or `getElementById`), then use `querySelectorAll` on it:

```
return document.querySelector('selector for the area of the page').querySelectorAll('ul.tag-list > li.tag-item').length;
```

You may also be able to do it with one compound selector (adding more on the left of your existing selector) depending on whether there are multiple matches for the parent container, etc.