# Get Times Listed for a Restaurant on a Page

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

How can I get the times from the following elements? I am using Selenium Webdriver and coding in C#. Both elements have the same class name?

[![From Inspect][1]][1]

On this page, 
https://www.yelp.com/biz/teds-montana-grill-aurora-aurora?osq=Teds+Montana+Grill

I need to gather the times displayed next to 'Today'
[![Today][2]][2]

to perform the following.
``

driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("nowrap"))...

This does not have getText as a method?

```
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tHwT2.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EQtxZ.png
```

Answer (score 1):

This is of course very brittle to any changes yelp makes to their HTML but you can just execute javascript:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("biz-hours")[0].getElementsByClassName("u-space-r-half")[0].innerText
```

Example js execute with the C# driver [Execute JavaScript using Selenium WebDriver in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6229769/execute-javascript-using-selenium-webdriver-in-c-sharp) .

Comment: getting a null value. I have posted the complete code.

Comment: Worked. I have posted the working code in my initial post.