# IJavaScriptExecutor is not working in AppiumDriver in C#. Method is not implemented

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, appium

I am new in Mobile automation, I am trying to scroll down page using AppiumDriver in C#. I am using code but it's throwing method not implemented exception:

[image]

I have working this issue from long time. Below are the code for AppiumDriver.

```
protected AppiumDriver<IWebElement> driver;
```

Comment: try this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6229769/execute-javascript-using-selenium-webdriver-in-c-sharp

Comment: In given url that is using IWebDriver while I am using appiumdriver. I have to scroll using AppiumDriver. I already tried it's not working.

Comment: Which version of AppiumDriver are you using?

Comment: make sure you are pointing to the right window before creating the `js` instance.

Comment: @GregBurghardt - I am using v1.15.1 version of Appium driver.

Comment: @supputuri - Yes, I am pointing right window.

Comment: It's better not to use JavaScript executor, it's flaky. There are better ways to perform a scroll like selenium interactions package.