# How can I make selenium executed an onchange event on a webpage

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I need to click a radio button, but the page does not respond

I use the following:
myField =  driver.FindElement(By.Id("payment:payRadio:0"));
myField.Click();

I get the following error "element not interactable"
I assume I need someway to execute javascript

```
<input id="payment:payRadio:0" name="payment:payRadio" type="radio" value="1" onchange="PrimeFaces.ab({s:&quot;payment:payRadio&quot;,e:&quot;valueChange&quot;,f:&quot;payment&quot;,p:&quot;payment:payRadio&quot;,u:&quot;payment:payOptions&quot;});" />
```

What do I need to do to fire up the onchange event?

Comment: `driver.executescript()` is about right. possibly `execute_script` depending on your underlying language. This method lets you run JS in the browser. You can either interact with your element with `driver.executescript('arguments[0].click()', myField)` or you can try and run that js directly since it seems to be in your element: `driver.executescript('PrimeFaces.ab({s:&quot;payment:payRadio&quot;,e:&quot;valueChange&quot;,f:&quot;payment&quot;,p:&quot;payment:payRadio&quot;,u:&quot;payment:payOptions&quot;});')`

Comment: I'm using C#. It says driver does not contain a definition for executescript

Comment: Good news is it does exist. C# just needs a little bit more faff. Have a read here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6229769/execute-javascript-using-selenium-webdriver-in-c-sharp

Comment: Thanks so much for your help. I made a few changes and it works now!

Comment: myField = driver.FindElement(By.Name("payment:payRadio"));
                  
                         //  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74175906/how-can-i-make-selenium-executed-an-onchange-event-on-a-webpage?noredirect=1#comment130966984_74175906
                         IJavaScriptExecutor jsDriver = driver as IJavaScriptExecutor;
                        jsDriver.Equals(myField);
                        jsDriver.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].click()", myField);